# getting custom taxonomies terms of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to get print names of custom taxonomy that i have created for products.

```
     function create_product_taxonomies()
     {
        // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
         $labels = array(
                   'name' => _x('product_categories', 'taxonomy general name'),
                   'singular_name' => _x('Product', 'taxonomy singular name'),
                   'search_items' => __('Search Product Category'),
                   'all_items' => __('All Product Categorie(s)'),
                   'parent_item' => __('Parent Product Category'),
                   'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Product Category:'),
                   'edit_item' => __('Edit Product Category'),
                   'update_item' => __('Update Product Category'),
                  'add_new_item' => __('Add New'),
                  'new_item_name' => __('New Product Name'),
                  'menu_name' => __('Product Categories'),

                  );

       $args = array(
               'hierarchical' => true,
               'labels' => $labels,
               'show_ui' => true,
               'show_admin_column' => true,
               'query_var' => true,
              'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product_categories', 'with_front' => true));

      register_taxonomy('product_categories', array('products'), $args);
```

i have added data through the wordpress admin panel. Now i want to Display the names of the categories in product.php file.

```
    function getLatestProducts()
    { 
       $args = array(
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'products', 
                'posts_per_page' => 12, 
               'order' => 'ASC'
             );
      $result = '<div class="col-sm-3">';
      $loop = new WP_Query($args);
      $i=0;
      while ($loop->have_posts()) 
      {
         $loop->the_post();
         $clink=get_permalink($post->ID);
         $desc=get_the_excerpt();
         $categories = get_terms( 'product_categories');
         $desc = strip_tags(str_replace(array("<p>", "</p>"), "", $desc)); 
         $the_imgurl = get_post_custom_values('_cus_n__image');
         $theimage=$the_imgurl[0];
         $the_locurl = get_post_custom_values('_cus_n__location');
         $theloc=$the_locurl[0];
         echo $categories;

         $result .='<div class="product-warp">';
         $result .='<div class="product"> <a href="#"><img src="/wp-content/themes/cake/images/pro1.jpg" title="" alt=""></a> </div>';
         $result .='<div class="product-name">';
         $result .='<h5><a href="#">'.$categories.'</a></h5>';
         $result .='</div>';
         $result .='</div>';
         $i++;

     }
    $result .= '</div>';
    if($i > 0){
      return $result;
    } else {
       return "";
}
```

}

it is just printing this arrayarrayarrayarrayarrayarray

Comment: ok bro just tel me that you also want that when a user click on the category name then it goes to a template where all products show of clicked category

Comment: Yes sir ofcourse i want to do this

Comment: clearly you are trying to print out an... as you may have guessed an array. I don't work in wordpress but this is simply solved by var_dumping out $categories and seeing what key you need to access to get the proper name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok bro you can use [get_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function for this purpose. Here is the example:

> **First Part**

```
<?php
     $args = array(
                 'orderby' => 'name'
             );
     $terms = get_terms('product_categories', $args);

     foreach($terms as $term) {
?>
         <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'product_categories') ?>">
             <?php echo $term->name; ?>
         </a>
<?php         
     }
?>
```

I only give you an example. You can paste my code where you want.

> **Second Part**

Now use the [WordPress Taxonomy Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/) for that when user click on one of your category and next page show all the related products of clicked category and also you must [read](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) this.

If you read `taxonomy Template` link then we go to next step.

Now you create a file `taxonomy-product_categories.php` in your theme root folder.

This create template for you taxonomy.

Now in this file here is the complete code:

```
<?php
    get_header();

    $slug = get_queried_object()->slug; // get clicked category slug
    $name = get_queried_object()->name; // get clicked category name

    $tax_post_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products', // your post type
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_categories', // your taxonomy
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $slug
            )
        )
    );
    $tax_post_qry = new WP_Query($tax_post_args);

    if($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
       while($tax_post_qry->have_posts()) :
          $tax_post_qry->the_post();

          the_title();

          the_content();

       endwhile;
    endif;

    get_footer();
?>
```

Once again I told you that I give you only a code you can merge this code in your theme.

Hope this'll help you.

Comment: just tell me when you succeed ... and don't call me sir

Comment: sir. what you have mention in the first step.i have applied it . it prints 8 times the whole category i.e 64 categories are shown. i just want to print once

Comment: hmmmmm tell me you want show all categories or only show the category of the POST

Comment: i just want to show name of the category and image of the category in products page.i their are 12 categories then it shows 12 images and a title with each image

Comment: it helps you or not and what is your image meta term name ... are you using woocommerce

Comment: use get_terms out of the post while loop

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029351/custom-taxonmy-image-option-in-admin-panel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106437/discussion-between-waqas-jr-developer-and-deemi).