# Display most recent post of each taxonomy for a CPT

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm trying to display the most recent posts from each custom taxonomy. The CPT is for 'member-services' and the taxonomy is 'services'.

Currently trying to combine two ([Getting Custom Taxonomies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36027820/getting-custom-taxonomies-terms-of-a-post) and [Getting Posts under Custom Taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165610/get-posts-under-custom-taxonomy)) scripts I've found online.

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

```php
<!-- Add in list of member services -->
<?php // Get the taxonomy's terms
    $terms = get_terms(
        array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'services',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        )
    );
    // Check if any term exists
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && is_array( $terms ) ) {
        // Run a loop and print them all
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) ?>">
                <?php echo $term->name; ?>
            </a>
<?php
        $post_args = array(
            'numberposts' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'services' => $term->term_id,
            );
        $posts = get_posts($post_args);
        foreach($posts as $post) {
            ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php   
        }
        }
    } 
?>
```

Real world logic:
Show most recent member-services (CPT) offered under custom taxonomies - 'product', 'price', etc on home page.

Currently:
Shows list of custom taxonomies, so get_terms seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes your get_terms is working but your get_posts is not working because you have passed taxonomy name in post_type.
I have done some changes in your code. May be this will work for you

```
        <?php
        $post_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'post_type' => 'member-services',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'sort_order' => 'desc',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'services',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                    'include_children' => false
                )
            )
        );
        $posts = get_posts($post_args);
        ?>
```

Comment: Please see my comment on Vishal's answer, could you shorten this code to help others? maybe leave just $post_args

Answer (score 1):

You have to write tax_query in get_posts() functions.

Just Replace

'services' => $term->term_id,

with

'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'services',
        'field'    => 'id',
        'terms'    => $term->term_id
    )
)

Comment: Ahh this is hard, between you and @IncipientInfo I understand the answer. You've made it clear what to change, however Incipient has explained why

Comment: Yeah, I think the updated answer of @IncipientInfo  will be work.